# SSIS Recordset Destination error

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

I have an SSIS package targeted at SQL Server 2012.

I have it deployed into the `Stored Packages` in Integration Services and then have a SQL Server Agent job which executes it.

The first part of the package which moves data from a number of tables from a live database into a staging database execute successfully. I then have a data flow task which uses a Recordset Destination to collect a list of IDs of other records to move into the staging database.

When I execute the package manually by doing a `Run Package` from Integration Services (through SQL Server Management Studio) the package executes successfully, running the dataflow task which uses the recordset destination, however when run through the SQL Server Agent job I get the following error

> Message
>   Executed as user: xxxx. Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 11.0.2100.60 for 64-bit  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.    Started:  09:51:49  Error: 2013-03-18 10:16:02.73     Code: 0xC000F427     Source: xxx_dataflowtask_xxx SSIS.Pipeline     Description: **To run a SSIS package outside of SQL Server Data Tools you must install Recordset Destination of Integration Services or higher.**  End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  09:51:49  Finished: 10:16:02  Elapsed:  1452.78 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step failed.

does anyone know how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Cross-posted: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36915/ssis-recordset-destination-error and http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/9ca73adc-a9fc-4ce6-9064-658a726d0e00

Answer (score 2):

I had simular problem, but with lots of other missed components to make my SSIS packages to be runned remotely. Full installation of MS SQL Server (Select All components from Feature list during the installation) resolved that problem:
[image]